# JPA 2.0 with Eclipse unidirectional relationship @Column Annotation ignored

Tags: java, maven, jpa

i'm working on a jpa project. And my problem is, that my laptop is ignoring the @Column and @JoinColumn name attribute, but my pc doesn't. I don't know where is the problem ... I have clean and build the project (java maven project, eclipse link 2.5 is used) but he names the id field as "ID" in the database and not as "measureddata_id". On the other hand, on my pc, he names the id field as "measureddata_id" (working as itended).

So i assume, my laptop is ignoring the @Column and @JoinColumn fields in my entities.

The second one on my laptop is a clone from my repository and the files and dependecies (Version number of dependecies also)  are exactly the same.

Here are my both entities:

```
public class MeasuredDataEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "measureddata_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createTime;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @OneToOne
    private WpsProcessEntity process;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "measureddata_id")
    private List<AbstractQosEntity> data;

    public MeasuredDataEntity() {
        this.data = new ArrayList<AbstractQosEntity>();
    }

    public MeasuredDataEntity(List<AbstractQosEntity> qosEntities) {
        this.data = qosEntities;
        this.createTime = new Date();
    }

    public boolean add(AbstractQosEntity e) {
        return data.add(e);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }

    public WpsProcessEntity getProcess() {
        return process;
    }

    public void setProcess(WpsProcessEntity process) {
        this.process = process;
    }

    public List<AbstractQosEntity> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<AbstractQosEntity> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof MeasuredDataEntity)) {
            return false;
        }
        MeasuredDataEntity other = (MeasuredDataEntity) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (AbstractQosEntity e : data) {
            builder.append(e);
            builder.append("\n");
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

second entity

```
@Entity
public abstract class AbstractQosEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Hide
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;

    /*
    @Hide
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private MeasuredDataEntity owner;*/

    public abstract String getEntityName();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof AbstractQosEntity)) {
            return false;
        }
        AbstractQosEntity other = (AbstractQosEntity) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "data.entity.AbstractQosEntity[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

I'm thankfully for help!

Comment: Firstly copy dir with your project from one machine to another. Secondly compare directories to pinpoint the differences. You can do it for example with Total Commander (http://www.ghisler.com/screenshots/en/08.html). Without information how these two projects differ, I think no one can help you.

Comment: There are no differences between the two projects. The second one is a clone from my github repository. So they are equal. (The dependencie versions are also the same)

Comment: Are you trying to say that you checked there is no difference? What about your DB? Does it have same schema? How do you build? Do you use schema generation? Have you drop the schema and start all over? There are lots of stuff to check before stating two distinct environments are the same.

Answer (score 0):

And what about the eclipse link version on your laptop?